# D3 manipulating and filtering csv data

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm trying to parse a csv file to use with a line chart. The csv file is organised as follows:

```
----------


Row 1 (headings): Series, Year, Economy X, Economy Y, Economy Z....
Row 2 (value rows): Indicator 1, 2012,  38, 73.2, 28
Row 3 (value rows): Indicator 1, 2013,  41, 74.2, 24
Row 4 (value rows): Indicator 2, 2012,  38, 73.2, 28
Row 5 (value rows): Indicator 2, 2013,  41, 74.2, 24
 ....

----------
```

I'm trying to create 'Economy' objects' each containing an object made up of 'Year' (coded as 'label'),  'Series' (coded as 'series'), and the corresponding value (coded as 'value').

Following the example by 
[delimited.io](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/3/creating-multi-series-charts-in-d3-lines-bars-area-and-streamgraphs) I managed to produce the objects (see 2 examples below).

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
name: "Switzerland"
values: Array[20]
0: Object
label: "2005"
name: "Switzerland"
series: "Indicator 1"
value: 2.96
__proto__: Object
1: Object
label: "2006"
name: "Switzerland"
series: "Indicator 1"
value: 3.297018849
```

The problem is that I want to create objects only for ONE indicator in the csv file in view of plotting only the data for that indicator. I therefore need to filter out all the indicators but the one I want (for example "indicator 1").

The code currently reads as follows:

```
d3.csv("data/sample data.csv", function (error, data) {
    var whichSeries='Indicator 1';
    var xAxis = 'Year';
    var series='Series';
    var economies = d3.keys(data[0])
        .filter(function (key) { 
             return key !== xAxis && key !==series});
    console.log("economies",economies);

    var seriesData = economies.map(function (name) {

      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function (d) {
            return {name: name, label: d[xAxis], series: d[series], value: +d[name]};
            }
        })
      };
    });
```

How can I build seriesData only for 'Indicator 1'?

Thanks a lot!!

Terry

Comment: `filtered = data.filter(function(d) { return d.Series == whichSeries; })`

Comment: THank you!! Works beautifully. Cheers, T